# Rails lossless image compression in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-compression

Can we compress image size using carrierwave gem in rails.
I just tried "Piet" gem but its giving memory error on heroku server and gem 'carrierwave-imageoptimizer' just do compression for 'jpg' file.

Answer (score 0):

carrier wave gem supports compression for both jpg and png images
you can get the complete info here in its github page
https://github.com/jtescher/carrierwave-imageoptimizer

Comment: Ad per its documentation gem 'carrierwave-imageoptimizer' ignore png files.

Comment: imageoptimizer requires OptiPng dependency gem to handle png images. does your gem file is included with that. ref https://rubygems.org/gems/optipng/versions/0.2.1